# Boyd & Vandenberghe, example 3.34 — quasiconvex example

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Example 3.34 (Page 97 in my version) in their book defines $$\mathrm{PV}(x,r):=\sum_{i=1}^n (1+r)^{-i}x_i$$ for every $r\geq 0$ and $x \in \Bbb R^n$ such that $x_0 < 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i>0$. Then, they define $$\mathrm{IRR}(x)=\inf\{r\geq 0\mid \mathrm{PV}(x,r)=0 \}$$ and claim, for every $x$ in the above domain, $$\mathrm{IRR}(x) \geq R \Leftrightarrow \forall r\in [0,R): \mathrm{PV}(x,r)>0.$$

I see that $$\mathrm{IRR}(x)\geq R 
\Leftrightarrow \inf\{r\geq 0\mid \mathrm{PV}(x,r)=0 \} \geq R\\
\Leftrightarrow \forall r\geq 0: (\mathrm{PV}(x,r)=0 \Rightarrow r\geq R)\\
\Leftrightarrow \forall r\in [0,R) \Rightarrow \mathrm{PV}(x,r)\neq 0.$$

As stated there, $PV(x,0)>0$ and $PV(x,r)<0$ where $r\to \infty$.
Still, I can't see why we cannot have more than one root in between without additional argument.

Comment: [Listed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33414/339790)

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\forall r\in [0,R): \mathrm{PV}(x,r)\neq 0
\Rightarrow \forall r\in [0,R): \mathrm{PV}(x,r)>0$$
by the Intermediate value theorem, and the fact $\mathrm{PV}(x,0)>0$.
The other direction trivially holds.